# MYSQL not showing results on left join with id condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one named attandances to store punch in and out record AND other one is Calender where I have all the dates
Attandances:
[image: Attandances]

Calender:
[image]

I want to fetch those dates of month  where employee haven't punched in my query is as follow:

```
select a.employeeID, c.cdate
from calendar c
    left join attandances a on (c.cdate = a.date)
where a.date is null
and a.employeeID='1'
and c.cdate between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
```

But when I execute , it returns me 0 rows. Any suggestion what I am missing?

Comment: IMO may be related that you expect `a.date is null` and `c.cdate = a.date` to be true at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
where a.date is null
and a.employeeID='1'
```

These cannot both be true.  If the left join finds no records, date will be null and employeeID will also be null.  If it does find a record, date will be not null.  It looks to me like you just want to move the employeeID condition to your join clause:

```
from calendar c
    left join attandances a on c.cdate = a.date and a.employeeID='1'
where a.date is null
and c.cdate between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to receive some data load script, but because of the visualization in the images you provided, the query will never return results.

You are doing a `JOIN` between both tables by the columns `(c.cdate = a.date)`and then within the `WHERE` statement there are two opposite conditions, on the one hand `a.date is null` and for another `c.cdate between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'`, remember that when making a `JOIN`, the columns by which the tables will be associated are expected to behave in the same way same way, so you can't set opposite conditions between their values.

The query you are trying to get is similar to this in my opinion:

```sql
select DISTINCT calendar.cdate
from calendar
where calendar.date NOT IN (
        SELECT attandances.date
        FROM attandances
        WHERE attandances.employeeID = 1
    ) AND calendar.cdate between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think where you do

```
from calender c
```

should be

```
from calender
```

and then also

```
left join attandances a
```

should be

```
left join attandances on calender.cdate = attandances.date
```

Comment: Have you looked at aliases before? I suggest you [read this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: With AS not omitted though seemed like an error, my mistake